# how to turn tar file object to string

Tags: python, json, tar

I have a tarfile object with a few files in it, one of them is called `ffb.json`. I tried the following to extract that json string,

```
with tarfile.open(mode="r:gz", fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(p.results)) as tar: 
    for tarinfo in tar:
        print tarinfo.name
        if tarinfo.name == './ffb.json':
            print tarinfo.tobuf()
```

However, the `print tarinfo.tobuf()` doesn't print what I expected: `./ffb.json0000644000000000000000000000054313070524150012600 0ustar  rootroot00000000000000`

If I extract the ffb.json by hand, it indeed has legitimate json string in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) for tarfile, `TarInfo` only contains file metadata - "It does *not* contain the file's data itself."

Fortunately, you can pass that `TarInfo` object back into `TarFile.extractfile(member)` in order to get the file's contents as a file-like object (which you can subsequently `.read()` to get the raw contents). For example: `print tar.extractfile(tarinfo).read()`.

Alternatively, you could just skip the foreach loop and call `TarFile.extractfile(member)` with the filename directly (e.g. `print tar.extractfile("./ffb.json").read()`).